# @ByPassInterceptors in seam 3?

Tags: cdi, seam2, seam3

@ByPassInterceptor 
annotation is removed from seam 3 that i know .

> and as per **CDI** documentation , 
>   By default, a bean archive has no enabled interceptors bound via interceptor bindings.

so is it safe if i remove **@BypassInterceptor** annotation from project while migration from seam2 to **seam 3** ?????

are there no default interceptors in **seam 3** ??

i would appreciate an answer .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can safely remove those. The design between Seam 2 and CDI is completely different. If you don't want interceptors run either remove it from the beans.xml or the class.